# Dot products in commutators

Tags: definition, operator-algebras

Suppose $\hat r$ is an position operator, $\hat p$ is a momentum operator and $\vec c$ is a constant vector.

What does the [commutator](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Commutator.html) $[\hat p, \vec c\cdot\hat r]$ mean?

I see that you can expand the second term such that the commutator becomes $[\hat p, c_xr_x+c_yr_y+c_zr_z]$ but then one of the operators in the commutator is a "vector" whereas the other is a scalar? Perhaps I am interpreting this wrong.

What would the value of $[\hat p, \vec c\cdot\hat r]$ be? Given that $[x,p_x]=i\hbar$? where $x$ is a component of $\hat r$ and $p_x$ the corresponding component in $\hat p$.

Comment: Yes, I think that the interpretation that you pose isn't right, if it were then the commutator would always be zero (since scalar multiplication of a vector is commutative) and so the definition wouldn't have much content.

Answer (score 3):

Using
$$
\left[\hat{p}_m, \hat{r}_n\right] = - i \hbar \delta_{mn},
$$
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\left[\hat{\bf p}, {\bf c} \cdot \hat{\bf r}\right] &=& \sum_{m,n=1}^3 \left[\hat{p}_m {\bf e}_m, c_n\hat{r}_n\right] =  \sum_{m,n=1}^3 c_n \left[\hat{p}_m,\hat{r}_n\right] {\bf e}_m
\end{eqnarray} = - i \hbar \sum_{n=1}^3 c_n {\bf e}_n = -i \hbar  {\bf c}.
$$